# Add drives to Windows file explorer navigation pane

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, regedit

I want to display drives C: and D: in the same way that 'This PC' is shown in the navigation pane. I know the process I need to go through (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1194576/show-user-profile-folder-link-on-navigation-pane)), however don't know which registry location I'm supposed to be editing. Can someone point me to it? If possible, I would also like to add a specific folder within D: to the navigation pane.

[image]

I've tried the [solution](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4675-add-remove-duplicate-drives-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html) provided by tenforums, however this failed to add the drives.

Comment: Can you indicate how the tenforums solution failed?

Comment: I downloaded the reg file they provided and ran it as instructed, however my navigation pane was unchanged.

Comment: That solution is only for removable drives and does nothing for you. I don't think there is one for internal drives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) and [his answer to *Pin a folder to Navigation Pane in Windows Explorer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34595293/3439404):

**PinDiskD.bat**. Run to pin the disk `D:\` somewhere above the `This PC` in the *File Explorer* navigation pane. Run with any non-empty parameter to remove the disk `D:\` from the pane, e.g. `PinDiskD.bat x` (note the `:deleAll` label below).

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set "_icon=%%SystemRoot%%\system32\imageres.dll,27"
set "_name=d DataDisk"
set "_guid=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-0000-00000000000d"
set "_target=d:\\"

set "_regK=HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID"
set "_regE=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer"
if NOT "%~1"=="" goto :deleAll
reg add %_regK%\{%_guid%} /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%_name%" /f
reg add %_regK%\{%_guid%}\DefaultIcon /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %_icon% /f
reg add %_regK%\{%_guid%} /v System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 /f
reg add %_regK%\{%_guid%} /v SortOrderIndex /t REG_DWORD /d 0x42 /f
reg add %_regK%\{%_guid%}\InProcServer32 /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %%systemroot%%\system32\shell32.dll /f
reg add %_regK%\{%_guid%}\Instance /v CLSID /t REG_SZ /d {0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E} /f
reg add %_regK%\{%_guid%}\Instance\InitPropertyBag /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 0x11 /f
reg add %_regK%\{%_guid%}\Instance\InitPropertyBag /v TargetFolderPath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%_target%" /f
reg add %_regK%\{%_guid%}\ShellFolder /v FolderValueFlags /t REG_DWORD /d 0x28 /f
reg add %_regK%\{%_guid%}\ShellFolder /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 0xF080004D /f
reg add %_regE%\Desktop\NameSpace\{%_guid%} /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%_name%" /f
reg add %_regE%\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel /v {%_guid%} /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 /f

:endlocal
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:deleAll
reg delete %_regK%\{%_guid%}                                   /f
reg delete %_regE%\Desktop\NameSpace\{%_guid%}                 /f
reg delete %_regE%\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel /v {%_guid%} /f
goto :endlocal
```

**PinDiskC.bat**. Pins the disk `C:\` in the pane. The same as *PinDiskD.bat* except four foremost `set` commands:

```
set "_icon=%%SystemRoot%%\system32\imageres.dll,31"
set "_name=c SystemDisk"
set "_guid=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-0000-00000000000c"
set "_target=c:\\"
…
```

**D:\bat\PinCodePages.bat**. Pins a particular local folder to the pane. The same as *PinDiskD.bat* except four foremost `set` commands (double check validity of  the `_icon`, `_name`, `_guid` and `_target` variables):

```
set "_icon=%%SystemRoot%%\system32\shell32.dll,176" # any valid icon
set "_name=My Folder"                               # any valid name
set "_guid=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-0000-00000000c0de"    # a valid GUID (no braces)
set "_target=d:\Utils\CodePages\\"                  # any valid local path
…
```

Example how it looks like on Windows 10 after running all above scripts:
[image]

Comment: Awesome, thats exactly what I wanted! Thanks for all the effort. Just out of curiosity, is there a small tweak I can do to this code to pin a specific folder instead of a disk?

Comment: Of course. Read [Simon Mourier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34595293/3439404) again (_Pin **a folder** to Navigation Pane in Windows Explorer_ how-to). Backup the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel` registry key before applying it as there is a bug in the _remove the folder from the pane_ code snippet (deletes whole key instead of the specific value).

Comment: @LaurieBamber answer updated.

Comment: What a boss, cheers mate.